# Play2 JSON support for Byte

Tags: json, scala, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.2

How can I handle Byte in Json Scala API, for example parsing:

```
json.as[Byte]
```

Do I have to write own Reads?

```
implicit val ByteRead = new Reads[Byte] {
   override def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[Byte] = JsSuccess(json.as[Int].toByte)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yupp, you'd have to use your own implementation as there is no built in Reads[Byte].